# (Shiny) Data persistence in renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am using `renderUI` to change what data-entry widgets a user sees based on their selection in a dropdown. I need to preserve their entries - i.e. if the user inputs `5`, that input needs to stay `5` even as they move between different menus. Currently, data is being reset to the default value every time they change between views. How can I preserve data while using `renderUI` in this context? It seems to have to do with the reactivity of the input object referencing itself...

Minimum example below

```
#ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(sidebarPanel(

 #when which widgets are shown changes based on input here...
 selectInput(inputID = "dropdown", label = "dropdown", choices = c("number", "date")), 

 uiOutput("my_ui")
 )))

#server.r
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
 output$my_ui <- renderUI({

  #any user input here is lost (reverts to default) upon changing views
  switch(input$dropdown,
        "number" = numericInput(inputID = "num_in", label = "foo", value = 0), 
        "date" = dateInput(inputID = "date_in", label = "bar", value = NULL))
 })
})
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is. There are no multiple menus in the above code.

Comment: If the user chooses 'number' from the dropdown, they get a numeric input widget. If they choose 'date', they get a date input widget. The UI that gets rendered depends on previous user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will often see a function defined like,

```
`%||%` <- function(x, y) if (is.null(x)) y else x
```

that just returns y if x is null.  You can use this in your renderUI,

```
switch(input$dropdown,
       "number" = numericInput(inputId = "num_in", label = "foo", 
                               value = input$num_in %||% 0), 
       "date" = dateInput(inputId = "date_in", label = "bar", 
                          value = input$date_in %||% NULL))
})
```

Note: I changed `inputID` to `inputId`